# How to computer $f(\frac{1}{2})$ given $f(f(x)) = x^2 + \frac{1}{4}$?

Tags: functions, problem-solving

I have observed that $f(f(\frac{1}{2})) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(f(f(x))) = f(x^2 + \frac{1}{4})$, and when $x = \frac{1}{2}$, we have $f(\frac{1}{2}^2 + \frac{1}{4}) = f(\frac{1}{2})$. But I don't know how to proceed, or if any of these observations are helpful. How can I from this compute $f(\frac{1}{2})$ and what is the intuition or reasoning that would guide you towards the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote
$
c = f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).
$

We have
$$
f\left(f\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)\right) = f(c) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
$$
f\left(f\left( c\right)\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = c^2 + \frac{1}{4} = c.
$$
So
$$
\left(c - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 = 0.
$$
This means that the only possible value for $c$ (if such function exists, of course) is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you, that is very clear. It seems helpful to introduce variables in order to stay clear.